# LSTM, multiple binary array input and overfitting handling

Tags: python, keras, normalization, lstm, multiple-input

Now I'm working on a space environment model that predicts the *maximum Kp index* of tomorrow using last 3-days coronal hole information.
 (Total amount of data is around 4300 days.)

For the input, 3 arrays with 136 elements are used (one array for a day, so 3 days data). For example,

```
inputArray_day1 = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
inputArray_day2 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] 
inputArray_day3 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

The output is single one-hot vector of length 28 which indicates maximum *Kp index* of day4. I use dictionaries below to convert between *Kp index* and one-hot vector easily.

```
kp2idx = {0.0:0, 0.3:1, 0.7:2, 1.0:3, 1.3:4, 1.7:5, 2.0:6, 2.3:7, 2.7:8, 3.0:9, 3.3:10, 3.7:11, 4.0:12, 4.3:13,
       4.7:14, 5.0:15, 5.3:16, 5.7:17, 6.0:18, 6.3:19, 6.7:20, 7.0:21, 7.3:22, 7.7:23, 8.0:24, 8.3:25, 8.7:26, 9.0:27}
idx2kp = {0:0.0, 1:0.3, 2:0.7, 3:1.0, 4:1.3, 5:1.7, 6:2.0, 7:2.3, 8:2.7, 9:3.0, 10:3.3, 11:3.7, 12:4.0, 13:4.3,
       14:4.7, 15:5.0, 16:5.3, 17:5.7, 18:6.0, 19:6.3, 20:6.7, 21:7.0, 22:7.3, 23:7.7, 24:8.0, 25:8.3, 26:8.7, 27:9.0}
```

The model contains two LSTM layers with dropout.

```
def fit_lstm2(X,Y,Xv,Yv, n_batch, nb_epoch, n_neu1, n_neu2, dropout):
  model = tf.keras.Sequential()
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(n_neu1, batch_input_shape = (n_batch,X.shape[1],X.shape[2]), return_sequences=True))
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(dropout))
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(n_neu2))
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(dropout))
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(28,activation='softmax'))
  model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='Adam', metrics=['accuracy','mse'])

  for i in range(nb_epoch):
    print('epochs : ' + str(i))
    model.fit(X,Y, epochs=1, batch_size = n_batch, verbose=1, shuffle=False,callbacks=[custom_hist], validation_data = (Xv,Yv))
    model.reset_states()

  return model
```

I tried various neuron number and dropout rate such as

```
n_batch = 1
nb_epochs = 100
n_neu1 = [128,64,32,16]
n_neu2 = [64,32,16,8]
n_dropout = [0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8]

for dropout in n_dropout:
  for i in range(len(n_neu1)):
    model = fit_lstm2(x_train,y_train,x_val,y_val,n_batch, nb_epochs,n_neu1[i],n_neu2[i],dropout)
```

The problem is that the prediction accuracy never goes up more than 10% and over-fitting starts pretty soon after intializing training.

Here are some images of the training histories. (Sorry for the location of the legends)

- n_neu1,n_neu2,dropout=(64,32,0.2)
  [image: neu1,neu2,dropout=(64,32,0.2)]
- n_neu1,n_neu2,dropout=(32,16,0.2)
  [image: neu1,neu2,dropout=(32,16,0.2)]
- n_neu1,n_neu2,dropout=(16,8,0.2)
  [image: neu1,neu2,dropout=(16,8,0.2)]

Honestly, I have no idea why the validation accuracy never goes up and the over-fitting starts so quickly.. Is there better way to use the input data? I mean, should I normalize or standardize the input?

Please help me, any comments and suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Here's my [github](https://github.com/INDIsy/Keras) with code and input/output data :)

Comment: Please clarify your question, by including *only relevant parts* of your code *directly* in the question. Also, you are using way more than "3 arrays" as training, if I'm judging correctly by your GitHub. Can you state specifically what training procedure you are using, and what parameters you have tried?

Comment: Also, can you clarify on the task at hand? It seems like the output should be able to classify more than just one *Kp index* for the next day, right? I.e., there could be multiple holes at once?

Comment: Thanks for your help and comments. I edited my question more clearly. If there still remain something unclear, please let me know.

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't perform a regression task instead of the classification? I mean, it seems to me that you have an (a) ordered and (b) continuous prediction range, so that would make way more sense IMO.

Comment: Additionally, have you compared your data from the test and training set? It seems to me that they are drawn from two completely different distributions....

Comment: I thought classification is more proper since Kp index has discrete value. It is possible to use regression. If so, I should decide the range that output value fall into specific value. For example, output [0, 0.15) -> Kp 0, output [0.15, 0.5) -> Kp 0.3 etc

Comment: I just compared the distribution of Kp index of data set. Here's the bar plot [images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nObvI.png). I couldn't do that for the coronal hole array.

Comment: I think I can try regression and more uniformly distributed data set. Thanks :)